# How can i check download window is prompted?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a search page.

On clicking search it will show a jquery modal with processing image and redirect to results page.

I have download functionality also in the search page. If I select the download option,

the result may vary to 1 kb to 25 MB, and I can't put a timer to close the modal window.

Is there any way to find the download is prompted?

Or download is completed? So that I can close modal at that time!!

Answer (score 0):

Just make a popup that disappears when the user click anywhere else, like on [github](http://github.com/madrobby/emile).
It would probably be too much job doing what you requests that it is not worth it. Better just showing a dialog that the user can dismiss whenever s/he wants to.

Well, yes it would be possible to have a script that runs while the file is being served (PHP normally times out within 30sec) and have periodically AJAX-requests to see if download is completed (or aborted).